# Manejo de archivos en c imprime basura en lectura y posterior escritura

Tags: c

Hola tengo este codigo en donde lee un string desde un archivo que contiene nombres de la siguiente forma

```
Robert Fair
Amanda Insley
Daniel Berryhill
```

Este codigo compila a veces y otras no, inclusive cuando compila y lo ejecuto, en el fichero se guarda basura ademas de la palabra, por ejemplo

```
 ‚Jê2+b"¢?Robert Fair
B0Ê4Amanda Insley
Daniel Berryhill
êr&rGarry Puckett
```

Codigo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


#define fila 50000  
#define columna 50

int EXTRAE_DATOS(char *variable, FILE *file);
int NUMEROS_AL();

int main()
{
    int n,a,i=0;
    char **nombre;

    FILE *alias;
    alias = fopen("nombres_aleatorios.txt","r");
    if (alias == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError: El archivo 'nombres_aleatorios.txt' no se ha encontrado.\n");
    }

    FILE *escribo;
    escribo = fopen("nombres_generados.txt","w");
    if (escribo == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError: El archivo 'nombres_generados.txt' no se ha encontrado.\n");
    }


    nombre=(char**)malloc(fila*sizeof(char*));

     for(i=0;i<fila;i++)
    {
        nombre[i]=(char*)malloc(columna*sizeof(char));
        if(nombre[i]==NULL)
        {
            printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    srand(time(NULL));       //Semilla para generar números aleatorios
    i=0;

    fseek(alias,0,SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(alias))
    {
        fgets(*(nombre+i),200,alias);
        i++;
    }

    for(n=0;n<fila;n++)
    {
        a=NUMEROS_AL();
        fprintf(escribo,"%s",nombre[a]);
    }

    fclose(escribo);
    fclose(alias);
    free(nombre);
}


int NUMEROS_AL()
{
    int num;
    //numero = rand () % (N-M+1) + M;   // Este está entre M (valor minimo) y N (valor maximo)
    num = rand() % fila-1; //Numeros aleatorios entre 0 y 30 -> quedará entre 1 y 31
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Has cambiado la pregunta y ahora mi respuesta no tiene sentido dentro del nuevo enunciado (la voy a borrar). No deberías hacer ese tipo de ediciones, si tienes una nueva duda, deberías crear una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Si, lo siento, es que el otro error era una estupidez, la pregunta de fondo es esta amigo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu programa tiene algunas inconsistencias:

**Tamaños que no coinciden**

```
#define columna 50

nombre[i]=(char*)malloc(columna*sizeof(char));
//                      ^^^^^^^ = 50

while(!feof(alias))
{
    fgets(*(nombre+i),200,alias);
    //                ^^^ 200 > 50
    i++;
}
```

Como ves en los comentarios, reservas espacio para cadenas de longitud 50 y, posteriormente, realizas lecturas de hasta 200 caracteres. Eso puede llevar a que el programa acabe pisando memoria. Si defines una constante... usala, por favor:

```
fgets(*(nombre+i),columna,alias);
```

Por otro lado, para mejorar la legibilidad del código te agradeceríamos que los `#define` estuviesen en mayúsculas (convenciones del código):

```
#define COLUMNA 50
```

De esta forma en el código es más facil diferenciarlas de las variables normales.

**Demasiadas iteraciones**

Este es el código que, supuestamente, genera el nuevo fichero:

```
for(n=0;n<fila;n++)
{
    a=NUMEROS_AL();
    fprintf(escribo,"%s",nombre[a]);
}
```

Tiene un problema con la función `NUMEROS_AL()`:

```
int NUMEROS_AL()
{
    int num;
    //numero = rand () % (N-M+1) + M;   // Este está entre M (valor minimo) y N (valor maximo)
    num = rand() % fila-1; //Numeros aleatorios entre 0 y 30 -> quedará entre 1 y 31
    return num;
}
```

`nombre` tendrá `i` registros... que, dado que no tienes ningún control, podrá ser mayor, menor o igual a `fila`... no lo sabes ni vas a poder deducirlo en tiempo de compilación. Asumir que el generador debe darte números en el rango (0,fila) es erróneo ya que el rango correcto debería ser (0,i).

Por otro lado no entiendo ese empeño en usar variables globales para todo. Por favor, salvo que sea un requisito del ejercicio **no uses variables globales**.

Tu función debería lucir más bien así:

```
int NUMEROS_AL(int maximo)
{
    return rand() % maximo; //Numeros aleatorios en el rango (0,maximo-1)
}
```

Por cierto, desde C99 (que data de 1999) es legal declarar las variables en el momento de usarlas... como por ejemplo dentro del propio bucle:

```
for(int n=0;n<fila;n++)
{
    a=NUMEROS_AL(i);
    fprintf(escribo,"%s",nombre[a]);
}
```

Es una buena práctica reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible para evitar errores tontos.

Como nota final sobre este bucle, fíjate que no estás añadiendo un salto de línea al final de cada nombre:

```
for(int n=0;n<fila;n++)
{
    a=NUMEROS_AL(i);
    fprintf(escribo,"%s\n",nombre[a]);
}
```

**Fugas de memoria**

Tu programa tiene fugas de memoria. Así de claro.

Fíjate que para crear el array de nombres usas **dos** malloc:

```
nombre=(char**)malloc(fila*sizeof(char*)); // (1)

for(i=0;i<fila;i++)
{
    nombre[i]=(char*)malloc(columna*sizeof(char)); // (2)
    if(nombre[i]==NULL)
    {
        printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Y sin embargo a la hora de liberar la memoria únicamente haces un `free`:

```
free(nombre);
```

¿Qué pasa con las reservas de cada fila? Pasa que se pierden (de ahí que tengas fugas de memoria). Las liberaciones de memoria en el caso de arrays o anidaciones tiene que hacerse en orden inverso a como se han realizado las reservas:

```
for( int i=0; i<fila; i++ )
  free(nombre[i]);
free(nombre);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias master!!!